# Importing Hyper-V Virtual Machine is failing because destination path is wrong

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows Server that's running a Hyper-V Manager (v.10.0.20348.1). The Windows Server has 2 partitions: C:\ is 250GB for the OS, and D:\ is 16TB for data. The D:\ has 9TB free.

I have a VM that I'm trying to make a copy of, so I exported the VM to a folder (D:\export-vm) and that completed successfully.

So now I'm trying to import the exported VM as a copy (I want the original VM to remain untouched, and I want to have a second VM that's basically an extact duplicate of the first, but with a new name).

So I select the 'Copy the virtual machine (create a new unique ID)' from the Hyper-V import wizard, and it starts import but then fails with a 'Import task failed to copy file' error. The details of the error show that it's trying to copy files from the export location to a location on the C:\ drive, instead of the default locations specified in the Hyper-V configuration.

There does not seem to be an obvious way to change that path to point to the D:\ drive instead of the C:\ drive (where Hyper-V is installed and I guess forcing imports to go there for some reason).

I also tried doing the import from Powershell, but it also gives me the same error. Here is my Powershell command:

```
Import-VM -Path 'D:\export-vm\vm1\Virtual Machines\7A698D-41E8-45C4-CD5287931360.vmcx' -Copy -GenerateNewId -VhdDestinationPath `D:\clone-vm\' -VhdSourcePath 'D:\export-vm\vm1\Virtual Hard Disks\' -VirtualMachinePath 'D:\clone\' -SnapshotFilePath 'D:\export-vm\vm1\Snapshots\'
```

How do I make Hyper-V import the VM as a copy and store it in the correct drive/path?